# Cloud Native Buildpacks/Paketo with Java/Spring Boot: How to configure different JDK download uri (e.g. no access to github.com)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, buildpack, paketo

Having a Spring Boot app I tried to build it using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` goal `mvn spring-boot:build-image`. But the build fails downloading the `bellsoft-jre11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz` from `github.com`, since I don't have access to it from my build pipeline:

```
...
Paketo BellSoft Liberica Buildpack 5.2.1
  https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
  Build Configuration:
    $BP_JVM_VERSION              11.0.9          the Java version
  Launch Configuration:
    $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0               the headroom in memory calculation
    $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes  the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
    $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250             the number of threads in memory calculation
    $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                           the JVM launch flags
  BellSoft Liberica JDK 11.0.9: Contributing to layer
    Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.9.1+1/bellsoft-jdk11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
unable to invoke layer creator
unable to get dependency jdk
unable to download https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.9.1+1/bellsoft-jdk11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
unable to request https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.9.1+1/bellsoft-jdk11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```

Is there a way I can download the `bellsoft-jdk11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz` to a location accessible to my build pipeline and configure the bellsoft-liberica buildpack to use this instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/configuration/#dependency-mappings):

> Paketo Buildpacks may download dependencies from the internet. For
> example, the Java Buildpack will download the BellSoft Liberica JRE
> from the Liberica github releases by default. If a dependency URI is inaccessible from the build environment, a binding can be used to map a new URI to a given dependency.

Configuring bindings using the spring-boot-maven-plugin (or the Gradle plugin) requires Spring Boot 2.5+. If you are on an older version, you need to upgrade or switch over to [pack CLI](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/).

=== **Use pack CLI with bindings to configure a different JDK download uri** ===

[The pack docs](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/configuration/#what-is-a-binding) tell us about the general layout of a binding directory (`/platform/bindings` is later created inside the pack build container):

```
/chooseYourBindingsName
├── key-name-of-our-buildpacks-binding-configuration
└── type-name-of-our-buildpacks-binding-configuration
```

**1. Create bindings directory**

So let's try to create a fully running example! In order to hand over the binding configuration to `pack` CLI we need to **create a directory first**:

```
mkdir bellsoft-jdk-config && cd bellsoft-jdk-config
```

**2. Create file type, containing the binding key**

Now we need to create a file called `type` inside this directory containing the binding key for [the bellsoft-liberica binding type `dependency-mapping`](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica#type-dependency-mapping):

```
echo "dependency-mapping" >> type
```

A new file `type` should be present in the directory containing the string `dependency-mapping`.

**3. Choose JDK version from buildpack.toml**

As we want to change the bellsoft-liberica's download uri of the JDK, **we need to decide which JDK version we exaclty want to use.** The bellsoft-liberica buildpack's [buildpack.toml](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica/blob/main/buildpack.toml) gives an overview on which JRE/JDK versions are available inside the buildpack. For this example here I used the latest JDK version `11` which is configured inside the `buildpack.toml` like this:

```
...

[[metadata.dependencies]]
id      = "jdk"
name    = "BellSoft Liberica JDK"
version = "11.0.9"
uri     = "https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.9.1+1/bellsoft-jdk11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz"
sha256  = "786c48fa6429d6a3f0afb189a65f0a43772e42afbab836852b9a1fdfdb8fc502"
stacks  = [ "io.buildpacks.stacks.bionic", "org.cloudfoundry.stacks.cflinuxfs3" ]
...
```

**4. Download JDK**

Having decided on the version, **we need to download the JDK from the location provided inside the `uri` field to a location we have access to later inside our build environment** (since we don't have access to github.com). Let's assume, we have the JDK downloaded and available at `http://your-accessible-uri-to/bellsoft-jdk11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz`.

**5. Create file named as the sha256, containing the JDK uri**

Now we should create another **file named exactly according to the `sha256` digest value** of the `[[metadata.dependencies]]` section of the JDK version we chose inside the [buildpack.toml](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica/blob/main/buildpack.toml). This file must contain the uri of our downloaded JDK:

```
echo "http://your-accessible-uri-to/bellsoft-jdk11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz" >> 786c48fa6429d6a3f0afb189a65f0a43772e42afbab836852b9a1fdfdb8fc502
```

In the end our directory `bellsoft-jdk-config` should comply to [the pack CLI bindings directory docs](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/configuration/#what-is-a-binding) and looks somehow like this:

```
/bellsoft-jdk-config
├── 786c48fa6429d6a3f0afb189a65f0a43772e42afbab836852b9a1fdfdb8fc502
└── type
```

**6. Execute pack CLI with --volume for binding & BP_JVM_VERSION**

Finally we can issue our `pack` CLI command. Ensure that [pack CLI is installed on your system](https://buildpacks.io/docs/tools/pack/). Be also sure to also provide the exact JDK version number using the `--env BP_JVM_VERSION=exactJDKversionNumberHere` [environment variable configuration](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/configuration/#build-time-environment-variables), which matches your downloaded JDK version and the section in the [buildpack.toml](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica/blob/main/buildpack.toml):

```
pack build your-application-name-here \
    --path . \
    --volume $(pwd)/bellsoft-jdk-config:/platform/bindings/bellsoft-jdk-config \
    --env BP_JVM_VERSION=11.0.9 \
    --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
```

Now the bellsoft-liberica buildpack will download the JDK tar.gz from `http://your-accessible-uri-to/bellsoft-jdk11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz`:

```
...
Paketo BellSoft Liberica Buildpack 5.2.1
  https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
  Build Configuration:
    $BP_JVM_VERSION              11.0.9          the Java version
  Launch Configuration:
    $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0               the headroom in memory calculation
    $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes  the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
    $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250             the number of threads in memory calculation
    $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                           the JVM launch flags
  BellSoft Liberica JDK 11.0.9: Contributing to layer
    Downloading from http://your-accessible-uri-to/bellsoft-jdk11.0.9.1+1-linux-amd64.tar.gz 
...
```

Comment: What should the permissions be for type file and actual files? I am using it through spring-boot bootBuildImage (gradle plugin) and I am getting `failed to load bindings from '/platform/bindings': failed to read binding 'ca-certificates': missing 'type'`

Comment: Did you create the `type` file mentioned in step 2. via `echo "dependency-mapping" >> type` inside the directory you created in step 1.?

Comment: for my case it is `ca-certificates` I am trying to load so yeah I did `echo "ca-certificates" >> type`

Answer (score 2):

I create bindings:

```
/bindings/bellsoft-jdk-config
├── 786c48fa6429d6a3f0afb189a65f0a43772e42afbab836852b9a1fdfdb8fc502
├── a3092627b082cb3cdbbe4b255d35687126aa604e6b613dcda33be9f7e1277162
├── be27df8838a6d069a2212de5f46da4e39f33f087f2e77c8a725d0f7ec8b5273e
├── d9ff2d84528a2154ff669b85e6dbdee7f244194dcc64e0a8a1bedc470b3bcf56
└── type
```

Then created a Dockerfile that copies these bindings and builds a new platform based on the previous one:

```
FROM paketobuildpacks/builder:0.0.464-base-platform-api-0.3
 
COPY bindings /platform/bindings
 
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

```
docker build -t your-repo-url/java-builder-test:1 .
docker push your-repo-url/java-builder-test:1
```

then I configured the spring plugin to use this platform:

```
<configuration>
    <imageBuilder>your-repo-url/java-builder-test:1</imageBuilder>
    <layers>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </layers>
    <image>
        <name>your-repo-url/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
    </image>
</configuration>
```

This workaround worked, but you have to use correct directory permission.

Comment: I didn't try this approach, since Paketo/Cloud Native Buildpacks aim to free you from the need to write your own `Dockerfile` - so I would advice you to go with `pack CLI`. I have a working example on TravisCI - see https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-buildpack/blob/main/.travis.yml You should be able to adapt this to your CI system. It doesn't use bindings, but I described this [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65212256/4964553).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Java version in pom.xml to 17:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the java version in pom.xml file to 17 and it worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change the Java version in pom.xml and it will work. i have changed it to java 17. and it worked for me.